# How to prevent CKEditor replacing spaces with &nbsp;?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm facing an issue with [CKEditor 4](http://ckeditor.com/), I need to have an output without any html entity so I added `config.entities = false;` in my config, but some `&nbsp;` appear when

- an inline tag is inserted: the space before is replaced with `&nbsp;`
- text is pasted: every space is replaced with `&nbsp;` even with `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;`

You can check that on [any demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) by typing

> test *test*

eg.

Do you know how I can prevent this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: That behavior is browser dependant. I've tested right now to type in the demo your sample with Firefox in Windows 7 and I don't get any nbsp

Comment: @AlfonsoML you're right, I don't understand why but it seems that this behavior is specific to webkit.

Comment: I investigated this behaviour recently. When you type `"foo "`, the space at the end of block should be an `&nbsp;`, because otherwise it won't be displayed. Webkits and Opera do this. FF and IE insert normal space, so after `setData(getData())` the space is lost.
Now, what happens when you type next letter after `"foo "`? Webkits and Opera replace the `&nbsp;` with normal space. That's correct. But when you open an `<em>`, by clicking italic button in CKE, it blocks that native behaviour, so the `&nbsp;` leaves around inline elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't understand because for me it was just html, but rules seem to be different in a contenteditable!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These entities:

```
// Base HTML entities.
var htmlbase = 'nbsp,gt,lt,amp';
```

Are an exception. To get rid of them you can set `basicEntities: false`. But as [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-basicEntities) mention this is an insecure setting. So if you only want to remove `&nbsp;`, then I should just use regexp on output data (e.g. by adding listener for [#getData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-getData)) or, if you want to be more precise, add your own rule to `htmlFilter` just like `entities` plugin [does here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/entities/plugin.js#L150).

Comment: I added my own rule to htmlFilter and it works now as expected, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

Based on Reinmars accepted answer and the [Entities plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/master/plugins/entities) I created a small plugin with an HTML filter which removes redundant `&nbsp;` entities. The regular expression could be improved to suit other situations, so please edit this answer.

```
/*
 * Remove &nbsp; entities which were inserted ie. when removing a space and
 * immediately inputting a space.
 *
 * NB: We could also set config.basicEntities to false, but this is stongly
 * adviced against since this also does not turn ie. < into &lt;.
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16468264/328272
 *
 * Based on StackOverflow answer.
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14549010/328272
 */
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('removeRedundantNBSP', {
  afterInit: function(editor) {
    var config = editor.config,
      dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
      htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

    if (htmlFilter) {
      htmlFilter.addRules({
        text: function(text) {
          return text.replace(/(\w)&nbsp;/g, '$1 ');
        }
      }, {
        applyToAll: true,
        excludeNestedEditable: true
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Best answer so far! But careful, you are missing the global modifier on your regex, which means only the first &nbsp; will be replaced. Please change the regex to: `/(\w)&nbsp;/g`

Answer (score 1):

### Remove all `&nbsp;` but not `<tag>&nbsp;</tag>` with Javascript Regexp

This is especially helpful with CKEditor as it creates lines like `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, which you might want to keep.

**Background:** I first tried to make a one-liner Javascript using lookaround assertions. It seems you can't chain them, at least not yet. My first approach was unsuccesful:

```js
return text.replace(/(?<!\>)&nbsp;(?!<\/)/gi, " ")

// Removes &nbsp; but not <p>&nbsp;</p>
// It works, but does not remove `<p>&nbsp; blah &nbsp;</p>`.
```

**Here is my updated working one-liner code:**

```js
return text.replace(/(?<!\>\s.)(&nbsp;(?!<\/)|(?<!\>)&nbsp;<\/p>)/gi, " ")
```

This works as intended. You can [test it here](https://regexr.com/6f708).

However, this is a shady practise as lookarounds are [not fully supported by some browsers](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

[Read more about Assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions).

**What I ended up using in my production code:**
I ended up doing a bit hacky approach with multiple replace(). This should work on all browsers.

```js
.trim()                                                            // Remove whitespaces
.replace(/\u00a0/g, " ")                                           // Remove unicode non-breaking space
.replace(/((<\w+>)\s*(&nbsp;)\s*(<\/\w+>))/gi, "$2<!--BOOM-->$4")  // Replace empty nbsp tags with BOOM
.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ")                                          // remove all &nbsp;
.replace(/((<\w+>)\s*(<!--BOOM-->)\s*(<\/\w+>))/gi, "$2&nbsp;$4")  // Replace BOOM back to empty tags
```

If you have a better suggestion, I would be happy to hear .

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the regular expression Imeus sent, in my case, I use TYPO3 and needed to edit the backend editor. This one didn't work. Maybe it can help another one that has the same problem :)

```js
return text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, don't hesitate to add more details about the backend editor you used