# How to prevent CKEditor 4 from "eating" &nbsp; spaces?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in a custom CMS to edit HTML Emails which sometimes require   for vertical padding.

Seems like CKEditor removes some `&nbsp;` characters automatically. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

See [config.entities](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities), [config.entities_additional](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_additional), [config.basicEntities](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-basicEntities) configuration options provided by the [entities plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/entities).

This question [How to prevent CKEditor replacing spaces with &nbsp;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523293/how-to-prevent-ckeditor-replacing-spaces-with-nbsp) might also be interesting since it's somehow related.

Also note that your case WFM on [official demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full).