# ckeditor validation for spaces

Tags: validation, ckeditor

**How can i implement validation on ckeditor to prevent user from adding spaces only . Any answer within today will be greatly appreciated .**

following is what i tried for validations so far :

```
//Save note from ckeditor
    $("input.save_note").click(function()
    {  
        var note_id1 = $(this).attr("rel");
        var thiss1 = this;
        var profile_user_id = $(this).attr("rel1");
        var txt=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
        var no_space_txt = txt.replace("&nbsp;","");
//      var txt = txt1.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
        var editor_val1 = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText() ;
        var editor_val = editor_val1.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
//      if( editor_val == "")
//      {
//          alert('sak');
//          return;
//      }
        if(editor_val !=="" && editor_val !=="")
        {
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        var loading_img = addLoadingImage($(this),"before");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/" + PROJECT_NAME + "profile/save-note-in-editor",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "profile_user_id" : profile_user_id , "note" : txt },
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(jsonData) {
                if(jsonData){
                    $("p#clickable_note_"+note_id1).hide();
                    $(thiss1).hide();
                    $(thiss1).siblings("input.edit_note").fadeIn();  
                    $("span#"+loading_img).remove();
                        $(".alert-box").remove();
                        $(".alert-box1").remove();
                        $(".alert-box2").remove();
                        showDefaultMsg( "Note saved successfully.", 1 );
                        $(thiss1).removeAttr('disabled');
//                      $(".cke_inner cke_reset").hide();
                        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
                        $(".editor1").hide();
                        $("p#clickable_note_"+note_id1).html(jsonData);//to display the saved note in clickable p tag .
                        $("p#clickable_note_"+note_id1).fadeIn('slow');// To display the note paragraph again after editing and saving note.
                    }
                    else{
                        $(thiss1).removeAttr('disabled');
                        $(thiss1).before('<span class="spanmsg" id="note-msg" style="color:red;">Server Error</span>');
                    }
                },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
         });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You cannot make an empty note. Please insert some text.");

        }

    });
```

**I have implement alert to check if no text is entered but i want to check if user only enter spaces . please suggest some accurate way .**

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Comment: @zeantsoi No . i have used trim and replace but both are not helping at all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are evidently using jQuery, you can add [`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) as an additional check for your condition:

```
jQuery.trim(editor_val).length != 0
```

This will trim all whitespace from the submitted form and check whether there are any characters remaining. If the input consists only of whitespace, the statement will evaluate to `false`. You would integrate it into the following line:

```
if (editor_val != "" && editor_val != "" && jQuery.trim(editor_val).length != 0)
```

Comment: && jQuery.trim(editor_val).length != 0  - It worked . thanks @zeantsoi

Comment: I would recommend using a regular expression to search for that particular string.

Comment: i referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters . And it worked , now I am not getting &nbsp; in output @zeantsoi .

Comment: I can't upvote any answer as my reputation is less than 15 @zeantsoi