# How to prevent CK Editor replacing spaces with &nbsp and accepting empty p tags using a jQuery function inside laravel blade file?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I am developing laravel application and I have used Unisharp CKEditor for textareas. However it keeps accepting spaces as &nbsp and when pressing Enter key blank p tags. I like to avoid these using a jQuery function inside my blade file itself. Is it possible and if possible how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Earlier I used these code lines in config.js (public/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor) file, but it didn't work.

```
//Disable automatic filling of empty blocks
    config.basicEntities = false;

    //Disable automatic insertion when pressing TAB key
    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

    //Avoid empty paragraphs
    config.autoParagraph = false;

    //Break lines with <br> when pressing ENTER key
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried first and where you're facing problems. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846952/ckeditor-validation-for-spaces this answer helped me to prevent spaces. But how to prevent empty p tags when user pressing Enter key?