# How to prevent CKEditor to add a space (&nbsp;)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When entering text, CKEditor allows you to enter multiple spaces in a row, replacing them with design &nbsp;.

Is there a way to prevent the editor to automatically insert &nbsp; (leaving only the possibility to insert a non-breaking space by the combination CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE)? Way just inserts spaces. I then remove them on exit.

It is important to preserve the ability to use &nbsp;, &lt;, &gt;, &amp;!

Comment: look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9741620/2454790

Comment: config.basicEntities = false;

prohibits the use of &nbsp; and this is unacceptable.

Comment: yep, as it's written ;-)

Comment: if you don't use a non breaking space when multiple spaces are entered, they will just be collapsed back into a single space when rendered so it's best to just let it do it's thing.  Non techy people won't get why they need to put in an `nbsp` and will definitely forget they need to press ctrl, shift and space to enter it.  Techy people can just edit the source as they please

Comment: From the point of view of typography is not recommended to use multiple spaces in a row (that is why they are ignored in html). Probably it would be more logical to put the functionality in the option (albeit enabled by default), and don't nail it with nails to the core. At the same time, non-breaking space is needed for proper text wrapping, so in the classical editors he entered with ctrl+shift+space. This remark to respected developers.

Comment: What module is responsible for the conversion of two spaces in a row in the &nbsp;? There it cannot be disabled?