# How to prevent ckeditor to not add &nbsp; in blank html tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, ckeditor

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express installed in Windows 8.1 OS and using CKEditor in my project as per requirement.

I am new for CKEditor and using it in a proper way as well but the problem is by defining the html in source in CKEditor it replaces automatically

```
<div><i class="classname"></i></div>
```

with

```
<div>&nbsp;</div> or <div></div>
```

So How to prevent CKEditor not to replace it and save as it is?
I have got some solution but still little bit error I am replacing

```
<i class="classname"></i>
```

with

```
<div class="classname"></div>
```

but in between the  tag it automatically add &nbsp.

How to prevent it to not add &nbsp?

Here in below image is CKEditor is open and you can see in rounded area it automatically adds some space or tab in my code.

How to stop that?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this Post:
[CKEditor unwanted &nbsp; characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters)

> After some research I might shed some light on this issue -
>   unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box solution.
>
> **In the CKEditor there are four ways a no-break space can occur** (anybody knows more?):
>
> 1. [Automatic filling of empty blocks](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fillEmptyBlocks). This can be disabled in the config:
>
>    ```
>    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
>    ```
> 2. [Automatic insertion when pressing TAB-key](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.tabSpaces). This can be diabled in the config:
>
>    ```
>    config.tabSpaces = 0;
>    ```
> 3. Converting double spaces to SPACE+NBSP. [This is a browser behavior and will thus not be fixed by the CKEditor team](http://ckeditor.com/comment/33942#comment-45910). It could be fixed
>      serverside or by a clientside javascript onunload. Maybe this php is a
>      start:
>
>    ```
>    preg_replace('/\s&nbsp;\s/i', ' ', $text);
>    ```
> 4. By copy&paste. If you paste a [UTF-8 no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) or double-spaces CKEditor will convert it automatically. The only
>      solution I see here is doing a regex as above. 
>      `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;` doesn't help.
>
> Summary: To get rid of all no-break spaces you need to write an
>   additional function that cleans user input.
>
> *Comments and further suggestions are greatly appreciated! (I'm using ckeditor 
>   3.6.4)*

**EDIT #1**

Have a look at this.

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i= 0;
```

You can also can use this with span and other tags.

[The documentation to this.](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-removeEmpty)

> **Stop Removing ANY Empty Tag in CKEditor**
>
> There is a defined list of tags that is going to be removed if
>   empty(see dtd.js and $removeEmpty or run CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty
>   from console).
>
> - From HTmL
>
> To ensure the certain empty tag are not being removed, add attribute
>   ‘data-cke-survive’:
>
> ```
> <span data-cke-survive="true" ></span>
> ```
>
> - From Configurations
>
> Or you can configure the particular tag from not be removed:
>
> ```
> if(window.CKEDITOR){
>             CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (ev) {
>                 CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = 0;
>                 CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['TAG-NAME'] = 0;
>            }
> }
> ```
>
> By setting an element to 0 in the CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty, it
>   prevents the empty tags from being removed by CKEditor.

[http://margotskapacs.com/](http://margotskapacs.com/2014/11/ckeditor-stop-altering-elements/)

Comment: I tried your solution but not getting the result it still replace with the blank. I have updated the question please go through it.

Comment: Yes it is running as of now but for every html tag like i I have to put this line!

Comment: Hi KMathmann there is another problem comes in <blockquote>&quot;some quote comes&quot;</blockquote> here it adds &quot before and after the quote, so it takes some space in my page. how do I remove this?

Comment: Try "config.entities = false;"

Comment: Oh Mamikon Arakelyan was faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104405/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-kmathmann).

Answer (score 2):

This topic can be helpfull [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters#answer-11576414)

In short- You can disable Automatic filling of empty blocks in the config:

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

more information- [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fillEmptyBlocks)

UPD.

You can try this `config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g);`

From [official documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource)

> {Array} CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource Since: 3.0
>
> List of regular expressions to be executed on input HTML, indicating HTML source code that when matched, must not be available in the WYSIWYG mode for editing.
>
> config.protectedSource.push( /<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g );   // PHP code
>
> config.protectedSource.push( /<%[\s\S]*?%>/g );   // ASP code
>
> config.protectedSource.push( /(]+>[\s|\S]*?</asp:[^>]+>)|(]+/>)/gi );   // ASP.Net code

UPD 2

Hope this will help.

```js
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
{
// turn off excess line breaks in html output formatting for blockquote tag.
// In same way you can correct any tag output formating

ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'blockquote',
{
  indent : false,
  breakBeforeOpen : false,
  breakAfterOpen : false,
  breakBeforeClose : false,
  breakAfterClose : true
});
});
```

Comment: No, when I started writing, answer at the top does not exist. Sorry if this seems as robbery

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan I try it but no effect in my code. It overwrite it with the blank.

Comment: @padhiyar try this `config.protectedSource.push(/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g);` in your config

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan woow great as of now it is working but how it's working can you tell me in brief please!

Comment: @padhiyar This option add elements into the array, whom Editor should not touch. They are setting up on regular expressions

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan means the thing which are stored in array will discarded ok. there is another problem comes in <blockquote>&quot;some quote comes&quot;</blockquote> here it adds &quot so it takes some space in my page. how do I remove this?

Comment: @padhiyar You can use   `config.entities = false;` it will be stopped conversion for html entities.

Comment: But I do not know, if it will lead to other problems?

Comment: No it's not working and my previous problems remains same by adding this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104404/discussion-between-padhiyar-and-mamikon-arakelyan).

Comment: I updated my answer, If I correctly understand the problem, it will be help you a little

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan It's working now but my most important question is that I already asked to KMathmann as well that, Do I need to add this line for every HTML tag if any problem occur in future or now for any other tag?

Answer (score 0):

For the one who are using UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor

```
<script>
  var options = {
    fillEmptyBlocks: false,
  };

  CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', options);
</script>
```