# ckeditor Disable HTML correction

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the ckeditor in Kentico tool.
There is an 
    `&nbsp;`
getting added for empty div.

Example-

is transformed to

```
<div id="ctl00_fullLayoutDiv">
<div class="main-block" id="ctl00_divMainBlock">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Please provide any solution to remove the 
    `&nbsp;` 
getting added automatically to empty div in ckeditor.

Comment: I am using the ckeditor in Kentico tool.
There is an &nbsp; getting added for empty div.

Example-
    <div id="ctl00_fullLayoutDiv">
<div class="main-block" id="ctl00_divMainBlock"></div>
</div>    

is transformed to

<div id="ctl00_fullLayoutDiv">
<div class="main-block" id="ctl00_divMainBlock">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

Please provide any solution to remove the &nbsp; getting added automatically to empty div in ckeditor.

Comment: I can't say that this is a problem that i have had.  Could you provide a little more information about your configuration?  Kentico version, how you've setup the control, which toolbar set etc.?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164316/how-to-prevent-ckeditor-to-not-add-nbsp-in-blank-html-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164316/how-to-prevent-ckeditor-to-not-add-nbsp-in-blank-html-tag)