# Ckeditor stop converting br tag into nbsp

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor to write content and save content into database to display in preview mode in non editable. I have a challenge that the content should be display as it is as i write on editor mode. But when i press some enter on creator it is creating a blank p tag with br tag link :

```
<p>
  <br>
</p>
```

After i save this content into database, this is converting into nbsp tag so it will destroying my html as i create in creator  mode. Ckeditor is replacing this blank p into this :

```
<p>nbsp;</p>
```

How can i stop this tranformation, any configuration for that. I tried the following configuration but this is not working. I tried :

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

This is not working for me.

Comment: I found a solution of my similar problem on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741620/ckeditor-unwanted-nbsp-characters)